# What identity and/or access data are JWT claims intended for?

Tags: authorization, jwt

I am an application developer and am building a token-based auth mechanism for my application. Essentially, the user will log in with username+password, if the credentials are valid, my code will generate a JWT (probably going with a 30-minute expiry, at least to start with).

If they attempt to request authenticated resources, they will need the JWT stored as a bearer token in their HTTP auth header. When this happens, I'll verify/validate the JWT, and if its good, give them access.

Right now I'm struggling with a particular aspect of the design here and I was wondering what the security best practices dictate in such a situation, and that is: what information can/should I put as "claims" on my JWTs?

I guess to start with, I'm not entirely sure what the underlying *intent* of a JWT claim is, which might help point me in the right direction.

But basically, with respect to my authorization scheme, I'm wondering if it is a good practice (or not) to not only place something in the JWT that identifies the requester as a principal in the system (identification), but also to place claims on that token regarding access control; meaning, do I put a list of all my user's roles, ACLs, etc. on a JWT claim?

Beyond authorization-related data, what other information do you typically see (correctly) added to a JWT in the form of claims? Thanks in advance for any and all help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JWT's can be used for anything you want the server side to communicate back to itself or other services in the ecosystem in a trusted manner *through an untrustworthy client.* The user principal, display name, and resource authorizations would all be sensible. That spares the server from going to a DB to look these things up prior to doing work.

Use your imagination though. What are some things you server side *normally* has to look up in a database or in another service because the client isn't trustworthy? Which of those things is static at the user or session level? Those things make for reasonable claims, IMO.

Comment: Fantastic answer, and it makes the solution 100% obvious in hindsight :-) Thank you.

Comment: Would it be a good idea to store all of the user's allowed resources_ids in the JWT? It could make it too heavy

Comment: @JuanPerez It likely depends on how granular that resource list is and how expensive it is to build comprehensively ahead of time versus individually (per-resource) at request time. Ideally, you'd want to do a little math for a few options and benchmark and/or stress test to confirm. In some cases, you just want to invert the problem. Use the JWT only to *authenticate* the session. Use ACL's in the service (e.g., on the individual records) to *authorize access*. (I'd actually assume the latter is the more routine approach.)

Comment: To follow that up, I would personally tend to reserve in-JWT authorizations to *very very low granularity* claims, like `isMemberOf: [...groups]` or `isSystemAdmin` or `fullReadAccess: [...services | ...tables]` and `fullWriteAccess: [...services | ...tables]`. Broad authorizations like that.